# Set cookies are present in Postman but not in Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am writing a front-end app and I got stuck on setting token as a cookie in browser.

Back-end is hosted in heroku and front-end is running on localhost

My request from React:

```
export const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
};

export const login = async (data: UserLoginData): Promise<UserLoginResponse> => {
  const res = await axios.post<UserLoginResponse>(API_URL + "/login", data, axiosConfig);

  return res.data;
};
```

Express setup:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
///
...
///

export const login = async (request: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    if (isBodyEmpty(request))
      throw new Error();

    const { email, password } = request.body;

    if (!(email && password)) {
      sendFailResponse(res, 400, "All input is required");
      return;
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      user.token = await createToken(user._id, email);
      res.cookie("token", user.token, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });

      res.status(200).send(constructResponse("Success", user));
      return next();
    }
    sendFailResponse(res, 400, "Invalid Credentials");
    
  } catch (error) {
    sendFailResponse(res, 400, error.message);
  }
};
```

Response from postman:
[image]

Back-end repo: https://github.com/simsta6/botique

Comment: Could you show us the response your client receives please?

Comment: @MarcRo https://imgur.com/TCChQWC

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) the axios config for credentials is `withCredentials: true` instead of `credentials: 'include'` (as defined for fetch). I did not confirm this is the cause of your issue.

**Note** that you cannot access cookies in the front-end if you set them with the `HttpOnly` option ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)).

**Note** that you can never access the `Set-Cookie` header on the client-side. This header is listed as [forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) and is filtered out by web-browsers.

Comment: I changed to 
`  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },`

also in server side I added: `res.cookie("token", user.token, { sameSite: "none", httpOnly: true, secure: true });`

but `res.headers["set-cookie"]` is undefined